# How exchanges (Binance, Coinbase) record user trade into blockchain

Tags: blockchain, binance, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

My question is how cryptocurrency exchanges like Binance or Coinbase record users trade into blockchain technically.
For example when Mr.X buys BTC/USDT pair from Mr.Y, how does the exchange record these two Transactions into the blockchain. as far as I know, We have two transactions now, Mr.X has to sign a USDT transaction to Mr. Y's account & Mr.Y has to sign a transaction for Mr. X's BTC wallet on that exchange. I was wondering how exchanges manage network fees? & how they record these trades into blockchain
I also know Mr.X order will probably fulfill with different accounts but I just want to simplify my question
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know both of them are centralized entities so what happens is:

Mr X and Mr Y send their crypto to the exchange controlled wallets. The exchanges keep the record in their own DB/ledger who owns what. Then when Mr Y and Mr X make a trade the exchanges record that trade in their own DB/ledger and nothing is recorded on public blockchain. Now Mr X withdraws the crypto from one of the exchanges and it gets recorded on public blockchain (If he withdraws BTC then it will be recorded on BTC blockchain). So Mr X and Mr Y can do thousands of trades without paying network fees as everything happens in the exchange's internal system (they may have per trade fee)

DeFi - I have no idea how it works, as didn't dig into it :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, The problem is when Mr.X withdraws the crypto into another wallet and you check it out with blockchain explorer, the origin of this transaction is his own wallet on that exchange.

Comment: The exchange may call it Mr X wallet but truthfully it's fully controlled by exchange. The exchange has full control over the wallet. They can refuse to let Mr X withdraw his crypto or for example government can seize the exchange's infrastructure and no one will be able to withdraw.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how cryptocurrency exchanges like Binance or Coinbase record users trade into blockchain technically. For example when Mr.X buys BTC/USDT pair from Mr.Y, how does the exchange record these two Transactions into the blockchain.

They do not. Your assumption is incorrect.

If you want to know exchanges that record trades to blockchain check Uniswap, SushiSwap, Kyber, Serum decentralised exchanges, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely you will see that the address where you top up to the exchange and the address where you transfer out when you withdraw are in most cases not the same. After you top up your digital currency to the exchange via the blockchain, the exchange will record the amount of your top up, at which point you can see your asset, but he is not the asset on the blockchain. You can interpret it as a record. You can use it to make transactions similar to BTC/USDT. It will only be recorded on the blockchain when you top up or withdraw.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ares0X. What is meant by "but he is not the asset on the blockchain". May need re-wording for easier understanding.

Comment: Perhaps we can use PayPal as an example. We can recharge PayPal, but the recharge money actually goes to the PayPal bank account. The PayPal balance we see is the equivalent of the digital currency balance we have in our Binance account. But the real money is stored in the bank account.